# iOS/Xamarin UICollectionViewCell loads late

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a weird issue in an iOS app written in Xamarin. That happens is that the lower left item from time to time loads late.

[image: Weird issue]

I'm not quite sure which information is relevant to this issue, since I tried to remove almost all complexity (stuff like custom delegate and and UICollectionViewFlowLayout)

What makes this even weirder is that when it loads it is shown for about a second and then disappears, until i start scrolling past it.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Comment: this is a banner? Which kind (Google ADMob?)

Comment: No actually it's a cell like the others, but it's user uploaded images so the quality are usually quite dubious :)

Comment: seems that is a banner injected in your cell (seem a iPhone ads) and some SDK till more then 50% of view it's not shown to user doesn't show content...